# Error #2006 when migrating from flex 3.6 to 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I need to migrate Flex 3.6 app to Flex 4. I have imported Flex 3.6 project to Flash Builder 4.7 and fixed all errors according to this tutorial:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/migrating-flex-apps-part1.html

Now when I try to run application, it fail with this error:

```
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildAt()
    at mx.core::Container/getChildAt()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\Container.as:2751]
    at mx.core::Container/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::getLayoutChildAt()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\Container.as:501]
    at mx.containers.utilityClasses::CanvasLayout/measure()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\containers\utilityClasses\CanvasLayout.as:198]
    at mx.core::LayoutContainer/measure()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\LayoutContainer.as:432]
    at mx.core::Application/measure()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\Application.as:1124]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::measureSizes()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8506]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8430]
    at mx.core::Container/validateSize()[C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\core\Container.as:3280]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:665]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:792]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

This error is entirely inside Flash framework stack, so it gives me zero information on how to solve it.
What might cause this error?

Comment: Start by removing all components from your app and then re-adding them one by one until this error occurs. That way you can at least identify which component is causing the error.

Comment: It looks like the error occurs in the measure phase of the component life cycle, and that it is measuring the size of the `Application` object itself. Your app seems to be using the "absolute" layout (b/c the measuring is being done by `CanvasLayout`) ... @RIAstar's advice should hopefully lead you to the culprit quickly since it's occurring at the top level. You might try changing the layout (as a test only), as well as migrating to `<s:Application>` instead of `<mx:Application>` -- but that may involve more refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with Flex 4 try to use getElementAt() instead of getChildAt()